# Why is my simulation getting stucked while doing .tran

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to make a circuit with "ideal" thyristors (properties in the final), and I am getting the circuit simulation stuck at some point. I have -previously- solved this by adding a LP filter in parallel with the load, but this time seems to not have fixed it. Also, have some problems with triggering all the thyristors with one source, so now I do it with 1 for each one and solved that also. All of this is done in LTSpice, and using the default configurations (just changed to check the integration methods but did not helped).

[image: Problem circuit]

[image: Transient analysis]

Values to understand the circuit:

Trigger current: `PULSE(0 0.001 4m 1u 1u 1m 20m)`

Thyristor:

```
.subckt tiristor anodo gate katodo
S 4 1 3 2 sideal
RS 3 2 1G
RLL 3 2 1k
D Anodo 4 dideal
F 2 3 POLY(2) Vc1 Vc2 0 (1)(.05)
Vc1 gate katodo 0V
Vc2 1 katodo 0V
R 3 katodo 1T
C 3 2 1n ic=0
.model sideal vswitch ron=0.01 roff=10g voff=.1 von=1
.model dideal d n=.1
.ends
```

Tran: `.tran 20m`

For half-wave rectifiers, this setup was working correctly, but for full it seems to flaw.

Comment: Try adding a small value resistor in series with the sinewave voltage source V1.

Comment: Thyristor gate current should always be relative to the Cathode. Your gate current is sourced from ground. The Cathode isn't grounded for any of your Thyristors. You may have cases where the gate is reversed biased and the current source will be confused. Certainly a problem in a real circuit, my LTSpice skills are weak, I can't tell if it will be a problem here.

Comment: I1..I4 should be " voltages generators".

Comment: Thanks! @Antonio51, you solved my problem, I had previously used current sources but it did not work. Now it does, so I learned something new :D!